# How to get base chronometer value in notification?

Tags: android, kotlin, chronometer

i have a problem with chronometer in Notification. I want to get current tick if notification clicked and parsing value to `MainActivity` using Intent. i have no idea about this case, i was try and result is always 0.

here my notification code with `RemoteView`

```
  fun showNotification(context: Context, value: Long, state: Int) {
            val isPaused = state == Constant.MusicState.PAUSED
            val intentTimer = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putLong(Constant.Key.CURRENT_TIME, value)

            val pendingIntentButtonPause = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, intentTimer, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, bundle)

            val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.item_notification)
            remoteViews.setChronometer(R.id.chronometer, value, null, !isPaused)
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonPause, pendingIntentButtonPause)

            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "199102")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentText("Test")
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setUsesChronometer(true)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 10, intentTimer, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))

            remoteViews

            builder.setCustomContentView(remoteViews)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                checkNotificationChannel(context, "199102")
            }

            notificationManager.notify(199102, builder.build())
        }
```

And this when i call function `showNotification()`

```
  this.binding.apply {
            this@MainActivity.musicState = Constant.MusicState.IDLE

            this.chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener {
                try {
                    if (it.text == "00.10" || it.text == "00:10") {
                        Chronotification.showNotification(this@MainActivity, it.base, this@MainActivity.musicState)
                        this@MainActivity.musicState = Constant.MusicState.IDLE
                        this@MainActivity.binding.buttonStart.text = "Start"
                        it.text = "00.00"
                        it.stop()
                    }
                }catch (e : Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            GeneralHelper.makeClickable(this@MainActivity, this.buttonStart)
        }
```

Thanks, any help or suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: what is the value here? How it is changing?

Comment: @DeePanShu i was updated my post :)

Comment: how you getting current value onNewIntent or opening new MainActivity??